# Magento 2.3.4 error while upgrading to Magento 2.4.0

Tags: magento2.3

I upgrade to version 2.3.4 to version 2.4.0 but I have an error. I have searched on google but it is not working.

```
Problem 1

- magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 2.4.5 requires php 7.0.2||7.0.4||~7.0.6||~7.1.0||~7.2.0||~7.3.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 2.4.5 requires php 7.0.2||7.0.4||~7.0.6||~7.1.0||~7.2.0||~7.3.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
- Installation request for magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 2.4.5 -> satisfiable by magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework[2.4.5].
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your generally problem is PHP versions issues.Your PHP version is **`7.4.9`**.But **`Magento 2.4`** PHP version  requirements is **`7.3`**.

So,Your Problem is you **`downgrade your PHP Version`** and try Again.

How to downgrade PHP Version For XAMPP:-

**https://stackoverflow.com/a/51906677/11908692**

How to downgrade PHP Version For ubuntu :-

**https://webdock.io/en/docs/perfect-server-stacks/upgrading-or-downgrading-php-versions**

**`THANKS.`**

Answer (score 3):

I think that given that you're upgrading from Magento 2.3.4 (which requirement is PHP 7.3) to Magento 2.4 (which requirement is [PHP 7.4](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html)), you could try to avoid system checks.

So try to run composer update with the param:

```
composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
```

This will avoid PHP version checks.

Comment: It's working for me. Thank you for share this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Because your current version is higher than 7.3.0, your php version is 7.4.9.
So you need downgrade to 7.3.0 and then retry again.